# Display Error message when connection or Invalid Username or Password in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried below code but i want to use MsgBox to display the error message (-2147217843)

```
Else
'Display errors..
For Each Err In objConn.Errors
Debug.Print Err.Description
Next
End If
```

Comment: `MsgBox Err.Description` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [MsgBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/msgbox-function) function with `vbCritical` style.

```
Dim Msg, Style, Title
Style = vbOKOnly + vbCritical                    ' Define buttons.
Title = "Error"                                  ' Define title. 
Msg = "The following errors have been occurred:" ' Prepare message template.
' Build message.
For Each Err In objConn.Errors
    Msg = Msg & vbNewLine & Chr(149) & " " & Err.Description
Next
Call MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)                   ' Display error message
```

You could also use `vbCrLf` instead of `vbNewLine` new line character.

Answer (score 0):

This is one google search away.

```
Msgbox(Err.Description)
```

Not sure how I can further enrich the answer with the current state of the question.